# Logstash-fowarder Installation on Mac

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

My work environment has couple of ubuntu and RedHat Linux machines. I configured **ELK** server on ubuntu and installed **logstash-forwarder** in client machines(ubuntu , Redhat Linux) and getting Logs successfully to Logstash.

I need to Install Logstash forwarder on a Mac book. I dont find any dpkg files.

1. I have rpm package. is it possible to install it on MAC?
2. I see that Logstash is replaced by file beat. can we run both filebeat and logstash-forwarder for same ELK server?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

To install Logstash-Forwarder on your Mac, you need to download the binary here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/logstash-forwarder-0-4-0

It is possible to run logstash-forwarder and filebeat at the same time. Be aware that the data structure sent to Logstash or Elasticsearch is not identical.

As it seems you just got started with logstash-forwarder I recommend to fully switch to filebeat as it brings the same feature set and has the most recent bug fixes. Filebeat can be downloaded here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I downloaded the binary but unable to install on mac book. can you plz provide the instructions, how to install it on mac?                  thanks in advance

Comment: It is best to follow the getting started guide for filebeat here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html